# Neither rospack find nor roscd can find ca_driver

Tags: ros, roomba, create

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Neither rospack find nor roscd can find ca_driver, I have tried installing on two different computer using exact instruction given on git page and also tried adding the ROS Path, passing full path to roslaunch but it says:

" [create_2.launch] is neither a launch file in package [ca_driver] nor is [ca_driver] a launch file name
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file"

Please help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259462/neither-rospack-find-nor-roscd-can-find-ca_driver/) by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like the instructions tell you to clone the repository in `~/create_ws`, but you actually need to clone it into `~/create_ws/src` and then cd back to `~/create_ws` to run `rosdep update` and the remaining build steps.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-04-17**:
Submitted a pull request to clarify their documentation: https://github.com/AutonomyLab/create_autonomy/pull/38

**Comment by [Awais](https://answers.ros.org/users/30062/awais/) on 2017-04-17**:
Thanks. It is now installed properly